# Send signal to main.js from module

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I creating firefox module in addon-sdk-1.17
I have this main.js

```
var panel = require('./panel.js');
```

and i want something like

```
panel.port.on("gotOptions", function() {
    // logic here ...
}
```

in panel.js

```
self.port.emit("gotOptions", data)
```

But it is not working. How i can dispatch event from module? (not content script)

Comment: See this exmaple: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29